# Unit test which asserts that current thread is the main thread [iOS]

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, unit-testing, testing

The question is does it make sense to write a unit test which asserts that the current thread is the main thread?
Pros/cons?

Recently I've seen the unit test which asserts the current thread for the callback of service. I'm not sure, that it's a good idea, I believe it's more kind of integration test. In my opinion, the unit test should assert method in isolation and should not know about the nature of the consumer of service.

In the iOS, the consumer of this service is intended to be a UI which by default has a constraint to run a code at the main thread.

UPDATE:

There is a call inside the service:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    failure(error)
}
```

It runs during the test suite and it's not mocked. Thus, there is a *delay* which breaks the rule that unit tests must be fast and unit tests should run at the same time as any other unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a call inside the service:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    failure(error)
}
```

It runs during the test suite. Thus, there is a delay which breaks the rule that unit tests must be fast and unit tests should run at the same time as any other unit tests.

This [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/383043/322570) explains what is the unit test.

Answer (score 1):

It's the UI layer's job to make sure it only updates UI on the main thread. You want to limit your work on the main thread to the bare minimum (basically, only UI work). Your callback will most likely be doing lots of other processing. It would be bad practice to put that all on the main thread, only because a small portion of those tasks (the UI changes) require it.

Comment: I agree with you that it makes sense to run the code on the main thread only if the updating of UI is the case. Any other calculations and logic should be performed on the background thread.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, as unit testing perspective, we should *not* focus on testing which thread is currently running. The purpose of writing test cases is make sure that *individual* units of source code work as it should, therefore we should focus on the results individually instead of caring about any other dependent layer (service) functionality; That's why the concept of *mocking* is exist in unit testing! If the SUT (system under test) uses a service that deals with asynchronous tasks, you should mock it, again we are focusing individually on testing a specific source code unit.

As a real world example, if we have a view controller `MyViewController` that has a dependency on networking layer `NetworkingManager`, as:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let networkManager = NetworkManager()

    func doSomething() {
        networkManager.getWhatever { isSuccess in
            // here is the side effect
        }
    }
}

class NetworkManager {
    func getWhatever(callback: (Bool) -> Void) {
        //...
    }
}
```

When aiming to test `doSomething` we don't have to care about `getWhatever` method, therefore we mock the `NetworkManager` and provide the appropriate implementation for our test; It doesn't matter on which thread `getWhatever` callback runs, instead, the assertion here is what is/are the side effect(s) that `doSomething` does when getting a success or failure from `getWhatever` without looking to its implementation.

However, if there an asynchronous task needs to be tested, you could use [`expectations`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestexpectation) to do so, nevertheless the usage of it should be for the purpose of observing individual asynchronous code without dependencies.

---

I'd agree with you that it seems to be more as an integration testing instead. For such a case, you might leverage asserting the `Thread.isMainThread` property:

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the current thread is the main thread.

Comment: "we should not focus on testing which thread is currently running": that is an extremely strong statement which can very easily be shown to be false. Suppose you have some properties in a library that you are testing that should only be accessed from the main thread because they are involved in the UI. You should test this rule by asserting that you are on the main thread each time you access the properties. If that comment was only meant to apply to this specific question, then you should have said so.